# Object null in View layer

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i have this problem:

O pedido:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="wp_posts")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name="post_status")
private String status;

@Column(name="post_type")
private String tipo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  
private List<PedidoMeta> pedidoMeta;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PedidoItem> itens;

@Column(name="post_date")
private Date data;

@Transient
private Usuario cliente;
```

O Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/detalhePedido/{id}")
public ModelAndView detalhePedido( @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) String pedidoid) {

    pedido = pedidoRepository.findOne(new Long(pedidoid));
    pedido = pedidoService.findCliente(pedido);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("DetalhePedido");
    modelAndView.addObject("pedido",pedido);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

a View:

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:object="${pedido}">
   <td th:text="*{pedido.id}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{pedido.cliente.nome}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{#dates.format(pedido.data, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

O erro:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: 
Property or field 'pedido' cannot be found on object of type 'com.ledolate.sys.model.Pedido' - maybe not public?
```

When debugging, the request is correct, with all the information, but when receiving in the visual layer it presents this error.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The issue is in your HTML.  You may want simply:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td th:text="${pedido.id}"></td>
   <td th:text="${pedido.cliente.nome}"></td>
   <td th:text="${#dates.format(pedido.data, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Or, if you are using `th:object`, then you're telling Thymeleaf that you are selecting the `pedido` variable and therefore shouldn't specify it again (unless `pedido` has a property also called `pedido`):

```
<tbody th:object="${pedido}">
  <tr>
   <td th:text="*{id}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{cliente.nome}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{#dates.format(data, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

The error message states exactly this.

See the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html) for examples.